# HTML/CSS div positions when reducing a window's size

Tags: html, css

We started a new "chapter" about grids and MediaQuery in class and I needed to do this. The assignment dramatically lacks instructions so I needed a hint about what to do.

Here's what I have to do (only 8 seconds video): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9f3FSxzl9jA

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
   <head>
      <title>Labo 8 – Grid </title>
      <!-- Laboratoire 8 – Web Adaptatif-->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <header>
         <div>header</div>
      </header>
      <main>
         <div>main</div>
      </main>
      <footer>
         <div>footer</div>
      </footer>
   </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
header div{
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
main div{
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 800px;
    height: 525px;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    margin: auto;

}
footer div{
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Here's what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/ojabdxet/
(it doesn't look so good in the jsfiddle window at the bottom, but more like what I need to do in a browser window)

I feel like I'm on the right track (maybe not) but my header and footer divs are not shrinking when I slowly reduce the size like they are in the video. Anyway, thanks for any help.

Comment: Positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go just change below code, also find my comment for detail.

```
main div{
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 800px;
    /* this will minus the height of header and footer and give you the expected result */ 
    height: calc(100vh - 220px);
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    margin: auto;

}
```